# is it possible to use shrinkwrap or something similar this way?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, shrinkwrap

[image: Sphere and Tree]

So here I have a Sphere inside which is a tree but I've detached it's branches so it's only leaves, now what I wanna do is trace the block so that I can use it for LOD in distance

[image: Same thing but with a palm]

I've done same thing with a palm tree, and as you can see all I did was trace the branches of palm and then make a plane, fold it and its done

I wanna do same thing with this Oak tree and I thought it'd be easy but using shrinkwrap or using method like snapping vertex to face didn't work since there's gap among leaves which make few vertex go on the otherside of tree and It looks glitchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, for a LOD object what you may be looking for is actually called [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

It can be easily obtained with Geometry nodes.

Add a *Geometry Node* modifier to your palm leaves object, then add a *Geometry > Convex Hull*, and it will automatically create a minimal geometry that encompasses your leaves.

[image]

Textures will not be preserved automatically.

Convex hull is the smallest fully convex shape that fully contains a base geometry, it will also have the least possible number of triangles.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but thanks man, that's what I was Looking for